# Order by with jpa, how to force it to sort by a specific variable?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a project where i query and sort using the Pageable class in Spring boot JPA.
Imagine, i have a Project object which has a relation to ForumPost which is basically a forum.
In my DAO definitions i have an abstract class that defines a uuid for all ids, a createdDate, lasModified, createdBy and lastModifiedBy. When i try to get a page of posts from a project sorted by createdDatem its is sorting by the PROJECT createdDate instead of the post.
I have

```
PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(Direction.valueOf(orderDir.toUpperCase()), order))
```

where order="createdDate" and orderDir="ASC".

How can i force it to use the post createdDate to sort?

EDIT: as asked in the comments

This is the query printed out by hibernate

```
select posts1_.id as id1_7_, posts1_.created_by as created_2_7_, posts1_.created_date as created_3_7_, posts1_.message as message4_7_, posts1_.project_id as project_5_7_ from projects projectdao0_ inner join forumposts posts1_ on projectdao0_.id=posts1_.project_id where projectdao0_.name=? order by projectdao0_.created_date desc limit ?
```

this is the POJO

```
public class ForumPostDAO implements DAO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7552574683834215423L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", unique = true)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 25)
    @Column(length = 2048)
    private String message;
    
    @CreatedDate
    private long createdDate;
    
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST , CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ProjectDAO project;

    public ForumPostDAO(ForumPostDTO post) {
        this.message = post.getMessage();
        this.createdBy = post.getCreatedBy();
        this.createdDate = post.getCreatedDate();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Short of creating a projection that basically doesnt include the relations or renaming the variable, nothing works.
What would you like to see though?

Comment: atleast the query and part of the POJO,

Comment: @Aman i've edited the post with what you requested

Comment: Why does it even send the Project object? I have lazy fetch and when i swap dao -> dto i dont use it

Comment: from the query it seems that you are passing `PageRequest` using the wrong repository.

Comment: How does the repository look like?